# sum columns based on header

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I have a tab-separated file1 like this (subset shown, real matrix 60x60000):

```
rowname   header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6 header7 header8
rowname1    1       1        10       2     3       1       10       2 
rowname2    0       7        200      3     37      1        2       1
```

And another file2 like this:

```
header1,header2
header3
header4,header5
header6,header8
header7
```

I would like to sum columns specified in each line of file2:

```
rowname    header1 header3 header4 header6 header7 
rowname1    2        10        5     3       10
rowname2    7        200       40    2       2
```

So column1+column2, column3 as it is, column4+column5, column6+column8, column7 as it is...

Some columns must be summed, others not, and not always the columns to be summed are consecutive.

If the columns are summed, the header of the first column needs to remain in the output file.

I am wondering if you have a solution with *awk*.
So far I just know how to store header entries:

```
awk '
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. If "not always the columns to be summed are consecutive", it is a good idea to provide input and expected output that illustrate that. You have used awk tag, so give it a try. Users are supposed to make their efforts before posting a question.

Comment: What are the headers of the output file supposed to be? Do you literally want the string `header` followed by an increasing number or should we take the header names from the second file?

Comment: Unclear about the relation between e.g. header4 versus header_4, and any significance in e.g. key3 versus just associating cols 4 and 5. Also header_n has no key reference: should un-keyed columns be listed without totalling, or omitted? Can a column be totalled into more than one key?

Comment: What do `key1`, `key2`, etc. have to do with it?

Comment: I edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to transform your original "matrix" by summing all columns which are stated on the same line of "file2" by replacing the first of those columns with the sum, and omit the remaining ones from the output?

Comment: Yes, the columns to be summed appear comma-separated in each line in file2.

Comment: @terdon, the header are strings, no numbers in them, just for the example I put some number to inform about the column

Comment: Exactly what are the separators on file 1: whitespace (multiple mixed tabs and spaces); or specifically only tabs; or some other invisible character? I can have code later today (4 hours) if nobody else posts it.

Comment: file1: tab separated

Comment: So how can we know what headers to use in the output? Please show us data we can actually use. Will the positions of the headers be the same? Can you show us some lines of your real data and the output you would expect from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
  FNR==NR{
    newhdr[FNR]=$1       # new header name
    newhdrcnt++          # number of new header names
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      hdrnames[FNR]=$0   # save new header names comma-separated
    next
  }
  FNR==1{
    # save column numbers for new header names in array hdrcols
    for (i=1;i<=newhdrcnt;i++){
      n=split(hdrnames[i], oldhdr, ",")
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
        for(k=2;k<=NF;k++){
          if ($(k) == oldhdr[j]){
            hdrcols[i]=(j==1 ? "" : hdrcols[i] ",") k;
            if (j==n) break
          }
        }
      }
    }
    # print header
    printf $1
    for (i=1;i<=newhdrcnt;i++)
      printf FS newhdr[i]
    printf ORS
    next
  }
  { # print data
    printf $1
    for (i=1;i<=newhdrcnt;i++){
      n=split(hdrcols[i], cols, ",")
      res=0
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        res=res+$(cols[j])
      printf FS res
    }
    printf ORS
  }
' FS="," file2 FS="\t" file1
```

Output:

```
rowname header1 header3 header4 header6 header7
rowname1        2       10      5       3       10
rowname2        7       200     40      2       2
```

Comment: I tested with the mapping `header8,header4,header5` plus `header6,header3,header1,header2`, and this reorders the output columns as `rowname header8 header6` and omits `header7`. Seems to me that any solution should at least preserve the total count in every row.

Comment: I don't get your point. Then add a single mapping for `header7` to preserve the total count per row, just like in the given example where `header3` and `header7` are left as they are.

Comment: Somewhere back around edit 3 of the OP, the keys list only mentioned the columns to be summed, and the accompanying example showed columns that appeared by default. Given the real file has 60+ columns, it seems a burden that the user has to list every column name that he wants in the output, rather than just the ones he needs to be summated. Granted, the spec is not clear, and the opportunities for strange keys are numerous.

Comment: @Freddy, it works as expected, amazing! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I hurt my brain, but using `gawk`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{FS="\t"} 
  NR==FNR{H[NR]=","$0","; next}
  FNR==1{for (i=2;i<=NF; i++) T[i]=","$i","; printf $1; 
    for (i=1; i<=length(H); i++){split(H[i],sp,","); printf "\t"sp[2]}; print ""}
  FNR>1{delete S; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
    {for (h in H) {if (H[h] ~ T[i]) S[h]+=$i}} printf $1; 
    for (i=1; i<=length(H); i++) printf "\t"S[i]; print""}
```

invoked as

```
./script file2 file1 | column -t
```

Output

```
rowname   header1  header3  header4  header6  header7
rowname1  2        10       5        3        10
rowname2  7        200      40       2        2
```

As per @paul_pedant comment to @freddy unspecified columns are dropped

**walkthrough**

Set up the `FS`

```
BEGIN{FS="\t"}
```

Load the list of columns to be summed into the array`H[]` adding "," to each end (to avoid mismatches in the regex to follow)

```
  NR==FNR{H[NR]=","$0","; next}
```

If it's the first row of the data file then load the column headers in the array `T[]` adding "," to each end of the header name `$i`

```
  FNR==1{for (i=2;i<=NF; i++) T[i]=","$i",";
```

...and print the titles as extracted as the first part of the sum specifying string

```
    printf $1; for (i=1; i<=length(H); i++){split(H[i],sp,","); printf "\t"sp[2]}; print ""}
```

For each data row, clear the summing array `S[]` and then iterate across the fields

```
  FNR>1{delete S; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
```

Checking each `H[]` for the field name `T[]` and if it exists then add the field value to the sum array indexed to the match `S[h]`

```
    {for (h in H) {if (H[h] ~ T[i]) S[h]+=$i}}
```

And at the end of each line, print

```
    printf $1; for (i=1; i<=length(H); i++) printf "\t"S[i]; print""}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I run it appears this message: "column: line too long"

Comment: Did you try it without invoking `column -t`? That is only to tidy up the spacing.

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049220/column-line-too-long-error)